# My molecule graphics are bunching all molecules in one place on the diagrams

Tags: graphics

I am working through McClain's book on Molecular symmetry, however the homebrewed visualisation package isn't working as intended. All the ball graphics for the atoms are bunching together at single positions. This should be obvious in these two images of chloroform.

```
chloroformList4 = {
{"C", {0, 0, 5231/10000}, {"1", "C3v"}},
{"H", {"H", {0, 0, 15961/10000}, {"1"}}, {"1"}},
{"Cl", {8281/5000, 0, -(58/625)}, {"1"}},
{"Cl", {-(8281/10000), (8281 Sqrt[3])/10000, -(58/625)}, {"2"}},
{"Cl", {-(8281/10000), -((8281 Sqrt[3])/10000), -(58/625)}, {"3"}}}
```

[image: The balling of all graphics about a point]

Comment: What do you do with those definitions to generate the plot? We need more detail to see if we can figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a copy/paste error in the second row?

```
In[57]:= 
chloroformList4 = {
    {"C", {0, 0, 5231/10000}, {"1", "C3v"}},
    {"H", {0, 0, 15961/10000}, {"1"}}, 
    {"Cl", {8281/5000, 0, -(58/625)}, {"1"}}, 
    {"Cl", {-(8281/10000), (8281 Sqrt[3])/10000, -(58/625)}, {"2"}},
    {"Cl", {-(8281/10000), -((8281 Sqrt[3])/10000), -(58/625)}, {"3"}}
};
m = Molecule[chloroformList4[[All, 1]], Bond[{1, #}] & /@ Range[2, 5],
    AtomCoordinates -> chloroformList4[[All, 2]]];
m["PointGroupString"]
ResourceFunction["MoleculeSymmetryPlot3D"][m]

Out[59]= "C3v"
```

[image]